# MySQL query returning different number of records each time it is performed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a relatively simple MySQL database table called 'inspitemsadditionaltemplate', with the following structure:

```
`TLA` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`Make` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Model` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`InspectionID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`ItemSequence` int(11) NOT NULL,
`AdditionKey` int(11) NOT NULL,
`AdditionCode` char(1) NOT NULL,
`AdditionText` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

The primary key is the all fields except the last 2.

The table contains about 70 rows, but the 4 I'm interested in are these:

```
'GBC', 'VC10', '', 'SI', 99, 1, 'N', 'Percentage left'
'GBC', 'VC10', '', 'SI', 100, 1, 'N', 'Percentage left'
'GBC', 'VC10', '', 'SI', 101, 1, 'N', 'Percentage left'
'GBC', 'VC10', '', 'SI', 102, 1, 'N', 'KPH'
```

I am performing this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM inspitemsadditionaltemplate WHERE TLA = 'GBC' AND Make = 'VC10' AND InspectionID = 'SI';
```

This should, from my understanding, return the 4 records shown above. When performed via the SQL tab in PHPMyAdmin this performs correctly, all 4 records are returned.

The problem is with a PHP script which runs the same query: (For the IF statement, $genericInspName does equal "")

```
if ($genericInspName == "")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inspitemsadditionaltemplate WHERE TLA = '".$tla."' AND Make = '".$make."' AND Model = '".$model."' AND InspectionID = '".$inspType."';";
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inspitemsadditionaltemplate WHERE TLA = '".$tla."' AND Make = '".$genericInspName."' AND InspectionID = '".$inspType."';";
}

if ($additionalresult = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
    while($row = $additionalresult->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $itemSeq = $row['ItemSequence'];
        $additionKey = $row['AdditionKey'];
        $additionCode = $row['AdditionCode'];
        $additionText = $row['AdditionText'];
        $insertSql .= "INSERT INTO inspitemsadditional VALUES ('".$tla."', '".$deviceId."', '".$jobNo."', '".$lineNo."', ".$itemSeq.", ".$additionKey.", '".$additionCode."', '".$additionText."', NULL);";
    }
    $additionalresult->close();
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Nothing here seems complicated, yet running this PHP script returns either 2, 3 or 4 rows, in no obvious pattern.

I've tried collation settings for the PHPMyAdmin and server but nothing seems to make a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've rebooted the MySQL server PC, made no difference.

The output is always the first 2, 3 or all four records:

```
GBC, VC10, , SI, 99, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 100, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 101, 1, N, Percentage left
```

or

```
GBC, VC10, , SI, 99, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 100, 1, N, Percentage left
```

or

```
GBC, VC10, , SI, 99, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 100, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 101, 1, N, Percentage left
GBC, VC10, , SI, 102, 1, N, KPH
```

I echo the sql every time I run the script, it is always the same:

```
SELECT * FROM inspitemsadditionaltemplate WHERE TLA = 'GBC' AND Make = 'VC10' AND InspectionID = 'SI';
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you may be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005). I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely easy, clean, and more secure than using non-parameterized queries. Also, [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) may help you choose between `MySQLi` and `PDO`

Comment: Are you sure `$tla`, `$make`, `$model` and `$inspType` are what you think they are each time? Have you tried inspecting/echoing/logging the query that's actually executed to check it's correct in each case?

Comment: Yes, I echo $sql every time I run the script, it never changes.

Comment: Please show us the output of $sql after several runs.

Comment: It seems that you don't need any SELECTs here.

Comment: The output is always the first 2, 3 or 4 records.

Comment: can you also echo the sql each time and check that as well

Comment: Will edit to show that.

Comment: Side note: why is the `model` field specified NOT NULL, but then you have empty strings in it? Clearly you have a need to not enter a value in that field sometimes, so putting NULL is much more clearly indicating "no value", than an empty string is. This is generally considered a poor DB design and can lead to uncertainty over the meaning of the field, as well as making it harder to test when the field is populated / not populated. Sometimes an empty string might be a valid "populated" value, perhaps.

Comment: In terms of your actual question - is there any other code running which could be altering the data in your tables simultaneously while you're testing?

Comment: Reply to ADyson: No, this sql is part of a function which does the same job for 2 other tables as well, reading from a template table and writing to a work table with additional data (jobNo for example). The other tables are updated correctly. The order the tables are processed seems to make no difference, I've changed it to no effect.

Comment: Your reply got me thinking, you are correct. The script was renewing the data in the template table from a csv file before trying to do the sql to write to the work table. When I removed the csv file so that didn't happen it works fine. All I have to do now is work out how to stop that happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was renewing the data in the template table from a csv file before trying to do the sql to write to the work table. When I removed the csv file so that didn't happen it works fine.